# Writing back a GROUP number in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-update

I have an existing app I can’t modify. It needs to execute a `SQL GROUP BY`, but cannot. However it can and does read a `GroupNumber` field from the same table.

What I’m doing now is executing the grouping SQL statement, processing it in code and writing back the `GroupNumber` to the table so that App can do its thing. What I’d like to do is execute a single SQL statement to do both the grouping and the writeback in a single step. I can’t figure out how to do this, if indeed it’s possible. Simple example:

```
  SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age 
    FROM Persons 
   WHERE .... 
GROUP BY Age 
ORDER BY Age
```

I execute this, then do

```
for ( i = 1; i <= result_set.n; i++ )
  Sql = “UPDATE Persons 
            SET GroupNumber  = “ + fixed( i ) 
       + “WHERE Age = “ + fixed( result_set.Age[i] )
```

I need to do this every time a record gets added to the table (so yes, if someone younger than me gets added, my group number changes - don’t ask).

Comment: Does the app call tables directly? Can you hide the table behind a view? Can you use a trigger to maintain the value? And what database system?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you want a trigger. However trigger definitions vary from database server to database server. I'll hazard a guess and say you are using some version of Microsoft SQL Server: the create trigger syntax and a couple of examples can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx. There might be some small complication with the trigger modifying the same table it is sourcing data from, but I believe you can generally do that in most SQL server databases (SQLite may be one of the few where that is difficult).

Try that and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Femi. You're right - it is SQL Server. I know someone who's into triggers and such. I'll give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are after, here is my best guess:

```
;WITH AllRows AS (--get one row per age, and number them
SELECT
    Age, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AGE ORDER BY Age) AS RowNumber
    FROM Persons
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY Age
)
UPDATE p --update all the people, getting their GroupNumber based on their Age's row number
    SET GroupNumber=a.RowNumber
    FROM Persons           p
        INNER JOIN AllRows a ON p.Age=a.Age
    WHERE GroupNumber IS NULL OR GroupNumber!=a.RowNumber
```

I use SQL Server, but this is fairly standards based code.